# Is there a way to print a variable x times depending on what number the user wrote in the input to decide x? [Python 3.8]

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm making a random name generator using the `random` module. I'm using the most popular first female and male names along with popular last names to generate two names, one male, and one female:

```
firstnames = ['Liam', 'Noah', 'William', 'Oliver', 'Benjamin', 'Elijah', 'Lucas', 'Mason', 'Logan']
lastnames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Garcia', 'Miller', 'Davis', 'Wilson', 'Martinez']
print(random.choice(firstnames) + " " + random.choice(lastnames))

firstfemnames = ['Emma','Olivia','Ava', 'Isabella', 'Sophia', 'Charlotte', 'Mia', 'Amelia', 'Harper', 'Evelyn']
lastfemnames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Garcia', 'Miller', 'Davis', 'Wilson', 'Martinez']
print(random.choice(firstfemnames) + " " + random.choice(lastfemnames))
```

So the output, after being printed, would give two random names like this:

```
Noah Jones
Evelyn Smith
```

I want to make an input for how many other random names they want after those two are printed; for example, if you make an input after printing the first two random names [Noah Jones and Evelyn Smith], I want to make an input for numbers, so if you input 2, another two random names are printed. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried for yourself for this problem?

Comment: I really only asked here because googling such a specific question would not give me a specific and correct answer, and I really did not have one clue on how I would code this.

Comment: Well, what do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? For each step, can you think of a way to do it? Did you write any code for those steps? Did something happen when you tried the code that you wrote?

Comment: For example: "I want to make an input..." do you know how to do this *generally*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

firstnames = ['Liam', 'Noah', 'William', 'Oliver', 'Benjamin', 'Elijah', 'Lucas', 'Mason', 'Logan']
lastnames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Garcia', 'Miller', 'Davis', 'Wilson', 'Martinez']


firstfemnames = ['Emma','Olivia','Ava', 'Isabella', 'Sophia', 'Charlotte', 'Mia', 'Amelia', 'Harper', 'Evelyn']
lastfemnames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Garcia', 'Miller', 'Davis', 'Wilson', 'Martinez']



def printMaleName():
    print(random.choice(firstnames) + " " + random.choice(lastnames))

def printFemaleName():
    print(random.choice(firstfemnames) + " " + random.choice(lastfemnames))

male = int(input("Enter the number of male names you want: "))
female = int(input("Enter the number of female names you want: "))

for _ in range (male):
    printMaleName()
for _ in range(female):
    printFemaleName()
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the number of pairs, use [the input() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

For acting on it, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
firstnames = ['Liam', 'Noah', 'William', 'Oliver', 'Benjamin', 'Elijah', 'Lucas', 'Mason', 'Logan']
lastnames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Garcia', 'Miller', 'Davis', 'Wilson', 'Martinez']
print(random.choice(firstnames) + " " + random.choice(lastnames))

firstfemnames = ['Emma','Olivia','Ava', 'Isabella', 'Sophia', 'Charlotte', 'Mia', 'Amelia', 'Harper', 'Evelyn']
lastfemnames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Williams', 'Jones', 'Garcia', 'Miller', 'Davis', 'Wilson', 'Martinez']
print(random.choice(firstfemnames) + " " + random.choice(lastfemnames))

noofchildren=input()
for i in noofchildren:
    print(random.choice(firstfemnames) + " " + 
    random.choice(lastfemnames))
```